# update a particular column with SSIS Package

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to update a particular column using SSIS package, however not sure what is wrong, below is the details.

I have 2 tables DETAIL & USER,
I am trying to build a package which will find the rows with below condition

```
DETAIL.ID <> 'EXCLUDE',
DETAIL.USERNAME <>'N/A',
and DETAIL.USERNAME <> USER.USERNAME
```

Once I have the rows I want to update the `USER.USERNAME` column in the `USER` table with the `DETAIL.USERNAME` field.

I have build a package as follows:

```
Source - DETAIL table
CONDTIONS -   DETAIL.ID <> 'EXCLUDE' & 
              DETAIL.USERNAME <>'N/A'
LOOKUP - USER table
CONDITION - DETAIL.USERNAME <> USER.USERNAME
DERIVED COLUMN - REPLACE USER.USERNAME with DETAIL.USERNAME 
DESTINATION - USER
```

This package is failing and giving an error where it looks like it is adding an extra rows instead of updating it.`enter code here`

[image: Screenshot of the package]

Answer (score 1):

Partially, this is expected behavior as there is no way to tell `OLEDB Destination` that you're updating and not inserting. SSIS Data flow task flow is meant for `read from source -> transform -> insert in destination`.

To achieve what you want, I have a simpler way:

Create a `Data flow task`.

- `Source` - DETAIL table. Use where clause to filter below condition:
  `WHERE DETAIL.ID <> 'EXCLUDE' & DETAIL.USERNAME <>'N/A'`
- `LOOKUP (no match output)` - USER table on user.username column 
  (This will bring all the records of Details which have different username than user.username)
- `DESTINATION` - staging table (stg_detail)

[image: img1]

Next, use `Execute SQL Task` to run batch update.

syntax:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.username = stg_detail.username
FROM user x
INNER JOIN stg_detail
ON x.ID = stg_detail.ID
```

Comment: What is the advantage of Data Flow Task + Staging Table + Execute SQL task, versus just using Execute SQL task to do an UPDATE..SELECT as a single SQL statement?

Comment: @mbeckish, staging table can be used to perform additional transformations if required before updating source table. It is easy to debug, find duplicates or mismatches through staging. Behavior of staging is truncate-and-reload hence no issues of data storage. UPDATE..SELECT will also work if that's what OP demands.

Comment: @mbeckish, the other advantage to Data Flow Task is that it's able to use more than just DB sources.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had slightly different requirements, as I was loading from Excel and needing to update one table and insert into another one.  But for the question of "how do you update a column in SSIS", I decided to go with a `Conditional Split` (which creates an in-memory table basically, so **use with caution**) and then an `OLE DB Command`, which allowed me to skip the temp table creation and use the output of previous steps in my `UPDATE` statement.

The Command Text is simply `UPDATE Table1 SET Col1=? WHERE ID=?`.

[image: SSIS Package Execution Path]

Ta-da! Fully-validated `UPDATE` in SSIS!